# Trying to use IF STATEMENTS to automatically fill cells

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: image of homework tracker]

As shown in the image, on column C they are supposed write down the homework they have for each class. I want columns D, E, and F to be automatically filled with "N/A" if the student puts "None" on column C (as in they didn't receive homework for a class). But, the columns automatically fill with N/A, even if column C doesn't say None! I don't understand this.

This is what I have so far

```
function myFunction() {
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

 for(var i = 2;i<=183; i++) {
  var homework = activeSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();

  if(homework = "None"){
    activeSheet.getRange(i,4).setValue("N/A");
    activeSheet.getRange(i,5).setValue("N/A");
  } else{
    activeSheet.getRange(i,4).setValue("");
    activeSheet.getRange(i,5).setValue("");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag to the question.

Comment: Also add a tag for the spreadsheet app.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between `=`, `==`, and `===`.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like JS.

if that is JS, you are using an assignment in the place of what you mean to be an equality check between the homework variable and the value "None"

Try `if(homework === "None"){`
and see if your results change towards your liking.

Disregarding language, your behavior is manifesting as if your predicate is evaluating the truthiness of an assignment to "None" and tripping your conditional. You likely want to investigate your equality operators to verify that the single equals sign is appropriate for equality comparisons.  In most languages, it is not.